# Creation Of Spring Roo Project In STS3.6.1

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-roo

I recently Downloaded Spring Tool Suite ,but i was unable to find the SpringRoo Shell in the Current version is there a way in which i can install Roo into eclipse..Please provide suggestion on how to move forward

Comment: This is a very broad question. Please research first, try some tutorial, and when you get stuck at a specific point and don't find a solution elsewhere, you are welcome to post a question.

Comment: What chrylis says is not correct... Roo is maintained and the team are developing new features... You can see https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO for more info. About your question, jmvivo is right on his answe.. you need to Install it on new STS versions.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Help -> Install New Software". You can found the Roo Support on SpringSource update site (included by default in you STS).

Answer (score 0):

I Found the solution for the problem Spring Roo 1.2.5 has a bug in it. You will not be able to run the batch file in ROO\bin folder. You need to replace Apache fleix framework  jar with new jar of Felix Framework version 4.4.1. You can get the jar from http://felix.apache.org/downloads.cgi. Then you should able to run the batch file without any errors